# What is Play framework web server

Tags: playframework

Do anyone know which web server is used by play! framework?

I'm planning to prototype a small intranet app using Play! and I am wondering whether I should use the default play web server or Apache or IIS as used internally.

I don't predict several instances of the application running nor a need for load balancing.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The internal server is [Netty](http://netty.io/).

Unless you are forced to deploy a Play application in a servlet container, don't do it. Play performs better on Netty as it doesn't need to jump through hoops to support the servlet standard, which shaves off quite a bit of overhead.

My preferred way of deploying Play is attached to a [screen](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/screen/) session, but "play start" should also do the trick :)

Comment: Thanks. I Definitely don't plan to run the app in a servlet container. However like every organisation, security and familiarity is always a consideration. It is easier for me to sell Play! to infrastructure if there is a way to plug it into our existing architecture.

Comment: That's why the "play war" cop-out is always available :)

Comment: Interesting. If you "play war", you can't win. ;)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - Wish I could up-vote your comment repeatedly. Awesome.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel .. _touché_!

Comment: @cdegroot - the screen session isn't available. Could you please provide it again?

Answer (score 1):

Use the play internal server and use apache IIS or whatever is preferred in your company as a reverse proxy.