# How do deploy a play application on google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, netty, playframework-2.6

This is my first time deploying an application. I have some idea about it but I am not sure if it is correct. How do I go about deploying a `play` application on `google cloud`?

1) I have created a package using `dist` command. I have the `zip` file now on my local pc. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying

2) Do I first need to create a `compute` resource on `gcp`? What configuration shall I use for the `vm`? My app is still in test phase so there are no external users at the moment

3) I suppose `play` uses `netty` web server. So do I need to install `netty` on the compute resource? I have looked online a bit but can't find a resource on how to deploy an application on `netty`.

Answer (score 0):

**deploy an application on netty**

Netty is not a web server/application server, but an IO framework which can be used to build web servers or any high-performant IO applications.

If you really want to use netty, you need to write an HTTP server yourself, or just use an HTTP framework built on netty.

If you want to build an application using netty, have a look at the examples on https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/

**Deploying a container to the Cloud using Google Cloud Platform and Kubernetes Engine**

Kubernetes is a way of orchestrating containers in the Cloud, enabling you to do things like auto-scale, fast deploys and manage running versions of containers. You simply create a container and upload it to a container repository. In this example I used Google’s Container Registry, it’s really simple to use and works brilliantly with their Kubernetes implementation.

follow this tutorial might help you with this

https://medium.com/beyond/deploying-a-container-to-the-cloud-using-google-cloud-platform-and-kubernetes-engine-10d8ee3aba86

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at the link you have shared. Referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634715/what-is-play-framework-web-server, it said that play users netty as web server. Did I get it wrong then?

Comment: Sorry, this might sound naive but does `container` mean the package which `dist` generated? I have been working in dev mode so far. I have read that in `play`, the application is deployed by first running `dist` command in `sbt`. This creates a .zip file Is this zip file the container? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying